# What is the correct term for the "int" part of List<int>?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, naming

When using generics in C#, is there an agreed name for the type of the generic used?

E.g. If I did any of the following:

```
var v1 = new List<int>();
```

or

```
IEnumerable<int> v2 = someData;
```

For v1, the type is `List<int>`, and for v2, the type is `IEnumerable<int>`, but what is the correct way to refer to the `int` part of the type?

Is there a correct name for the supplied generic in statements like the above?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters

Answer (score 1):

`int` in `List<int>` is a *generic type argument* bound to `T`, a *generic type parameter* of `List<T>`:

> To use `List<T>`, client code must declare and instantiate a constructed type by specifying a *type argument* inside the angle brackets.

See [*Generic Type Parameters*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters) section of Microsoft C# Programming Guide for the reference.